# как установить и запустить rhino 4 движок для java

Tags: java

Будьте добры скажите пожалуйста как установить и запустить движок для java rhino4
Я скачал архив rhino1_7R4.zip 
при выполнении команды

java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
из командной строки и менювыполнить
у меня открывается папка C:\WINDOWS\java

при выполнении команды

java -cp C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Oracle\Java\javapath\js.jar:. org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
выдаётся сообщение could not find or load main class

переменные среды CLASSPATH РЕДАКТИОВАЛ

Comment: Rhino - движок для JavaScript. На Java он написан. Если вы хотите запустить его REPL, то в документации пишут, что делать это надо так: `java -jar rhino-1.7.7.1.jar`

Comment: СЕРГЕЙ СПАСИБО ЭТО НЕОБХОДИМО

Comment: java -jar rhino-1.7.7.1.jar ПРОБОВАЛ  НАБРАТЬ В КОМАНДНОЙ СТРОКЕ

Comment: ВЫДАЁТ ОШИБКУ Uable to access jar file rhino-1.7.1.jar МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ РАСПАКОВАТЬ В ./lib НО ЧТО ЭТО ОБОЗНАЧАЕТ И ГДЕ НАХОДИТСЯ ЭТА ПАПКА